# Effect of dimension increase on the domain of attraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider a nonlinear system with two locally stable fixed points $s_1$ and $s_2$ which have domains of attraction $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively.

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be domains of attraction of one system variable ($x_i$) for $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively.

$d_1$ and $d_2$ are of dimension $1$ and in fact, $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the projections of $D_1$ and $D_2$ on $x_i$ space.

Please let me know whether the following argument is possible:

**As the system's dimension increases, sizes of $d_1$ and $d_2$ keep increasing simultaneously with a same or different rates. Or if you think that this statement is contradictory, why?**

Comment: How do you compare the notion of "size" in different dimensional spaces? Are you talking about their length, since they stay one dimensional along the way, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. As $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the projections of $D_1$ and $D_2$ on $x_i$ space, they are two simple circles. so we can consider the circles' radius as the notion of size.